# Using Prototype's Properties before Function's Prototype is Set

Tags: javascript

I would like to assign a property to a function's prototype and use that property prior to setting the prototype as the function's prototype (hard to explain). If I was doing this in Java, I would just create a public static final variable on the base class. For instance...

```
function Foo(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

function Bar() {
   this.prototype.A = 100; 
   this.prototype.B = 250;
   Foo.call(this, this.prototype.A, this.prototype.B);
}
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo); // Bar.A and Bar.B are now undefined, not what I
                                    // want to happen.
```

Potential implementation #1...

```
function Foo(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

var tempA = 100;
var tempB = 250;

function Bar() {
    Foo.call(this, tempA, tempB);
}
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo);
Bar.prototype.A = tempA;
Bar.prototype.B = tempB;
```

Potential implementation #2...

```
function Foo(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

var barPrototype = Object.create(Foo);
barPrototype.A = 100;
barPrototype.B = 250;

function Bar() {
    Foo.call(this, barPrototype.A, barPrototype.B);
}
Bar.prototype = barPrototype;
```

Does anyone have a preference as to which implementation is better? Or is there a more elegant way (no temp variables) to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why not just make the `A` and `B` private variables within the `Bar` constructor, and why don't you just call Foo directly with those variables?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to make `A` and `B` constants for function Bar. I want to be able to check the value of `A` and `B` externally.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to extend Foo's prototype and add additional attributes to it? For that you could use something like this:

```
function Bar() {
  new Foo.call(this, this.A, this.B); // It's a constructor, should use new
}

var proto = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
proto.A = 100;
proto.B = 250;

Bar.prototype = proto;
```

However, if you wanted to extend this further, then you're really looking for a *mixin* method, which will allow you to merge two objects together. **If** you're already using jQuery (note: definitely not advocating just for this purpose), you could use the **[$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)**  method:

```
Bar.prototype = $.extend({}, Foo.prototype, {
  A: 100,
  B: 250
});
```

If you're not using jQuery, it shouldn't be hard to find a similar method elsewhere (e.g. Underscore has one too)

---

If you want to have a *shared* variable, to be available to both `Foo` and `Bar`, then you could alternatively wrap their definitions in an [Immediately-Invoking Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and define your A and B private variables within this function:

```
(function() {
  var A = 100,
      B = 250;

  function Foo() { ... }

  function Bar() {
    Foo.call(this, A, B);
  }
})();
```

This would be more appropriate if A and B are more global constants, and not intrinsically linked to Bar.